# Is it possible to obtain new refresh token using other refresh token in OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Given the scenario:

- user authenticates and obtains refresh and access tokens
- after some time, when refresh token is about to expire user wants to obtain new refresh token using previous refresh token

Is it possible to obtain new refresh token that way?

Answer (score 1):

`Refresh tokens` usually have a very long lifetime. When a new `access token` is requested using the `refresh token` OAuth server can send a new `refresh token` along with the new `access token`. You can then compare if `refresh token` has been changed and update your current `refresh token` with the new token. The new `refresh token` is usually issued when you have configured sliding expiration for the `refresh token` and expiration time is approaching.

Comment: Is that 'sliding expiration' part of standard or vendor-specific?

Comment: I think it is vender specific. In the spec it says `Issuing a refresh token is optional at the discretion of the
   authorization server` https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.5